# open coc-definition in new split in coc

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

I am using `coc.vim` in neovim. `coc.vim` suggests the following mapping for jumping to the definition of a class/method.

```
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
```

If there is only a single matching definition, pressing `gd` will immediately open the definition in the current window.

If there are multiple matches, coc shows a preview window with the list of matching files. It is possible to scroll through the results with `j`/`k`. Pressing tab displays the following prompt, for opening the current selection.

```
Choose action:
[o]pen, (p)review, (q)uickfix, (t)abe, (d)rop, (v)split, (s)plit:
```

- Is the above prompt a standard part of `vim` or is it part of `coc.vim`?
- Is it possible to force this prompt, even if there is only a single hit?
- If not, how can I force vim to open `coc-definition` in a new vertical split?

Comment: That doesn't look like any vim prompt I've ever seen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I inject my [own way of opening files in CoC](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/vimrc_core.vim#L1130) with:

```
let g:coc_user_config = {}
let g:coc_user_config['coc.preferences.jumpCommand'] = ':SplitIfNotOpen4COC'
```

Then the command is [defined in my lh-vim-lib plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/plugin/lhvl.vim#L63) to search if the buffer is already opened or not. Having more control is possible.

To use the prompt already provided by CoC, you may have to search in its source code.

Comment: Thank you. Setting `coc.preferences.jumpCommand` to `vsp` worked. I have just started learning vim, so I couldn't fully understand `lh#coc#_split_open`. I don't want to copy paste blindly, and will give it a second look after learning vimscript.

Comment: [`lh#coc#_split_open()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/coc.vim#L58) is a COC specific wrapper around another function of mine: the one that is a kind of `:sb_or_sp` (if it were to exist).

Comment: After reading a few tutorials, I could understand parts of your function code. The first argument, if prefixed with `+`, is stored in `where` variable and is executed as an ex command when the file is not open in any existing window. But what is the content of the `where` variable? Is it set by `coc`, or do you use pass it when manually invoking `SplitIfNotOpen4C0C`?

Comment: It's COC doing. It encodes a few things in the filenames in order to specify the position the cursor shall jump to. NB: my function will return a negative number only if it cannot jump into a window (new or not) containing the requested file.

Comment: This simply does not work for me.

Comment: @StevenLu. Could you be more specific about what you have already done? And how you've configured coc? First do you have a command that does the job by itself? Then, are you able to replace, first, the default opening policy with `:sp` fr instance? Eventually if both previous steps are working correctly, you could be able to have it working by using the custom command instead of `:sp`. Just be aware that COC injects a position prefix, hence my function.

Comment: @LucHermitte I resolved this issue quite satisfactorily based on what I gleaned from https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/1249, I have 4 different vim maps which implement the 4 ways to open definition: regular (in present window), in split, in vsplit, in new tab. The main thing was that the coc instructions/doc never mentioned these alternate ways of going to definition. As for going to references or implementation I use them less and also the cocList comes with binds for these different opening modalities.

Answer (score 11):

You can call the action jumpDefinition with a [command as argument](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/1249):

```
nmap <silent> gs :call CocAction('jumpDefinition', 'split')<CR>
nmap <silent> gd :call CocAction('jumpDefinition', 'vsplit')<CR>
nmap <silent> gt :call CocAction('jumpDefinition', 'tabe')<CR>
```

To get more information:

```
:h coc-action-jumpDefinition
```

Answer (score 1):

open coc config use ":CocConfig" and add this config to your coc-settings.json

```
"coc.preferences.jumpCommand": "vsplit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nmap <silent> gd :call CocAction('jumpDefinition', 'vsplit')<CR>
```

This does **NOT WORK** with vim-go plugin use, because vim-go or other plugin will cover the map, it will remap you key with `<buffer>` options, that will make you key be remapped in current buffer.

my current solution is, map it when enter buffer.

```
"The functions that will run when a buffer is entered
func! CallAtBufEnter()
    "for `gd` jump, vsp than jump
    nmap <buffer> gd :call CocAction('jumpDefinition', 'vsplit')<CR>
endfunc
autocmd BufEnter * call CallAtBufEnter()
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! My general advice would be to disable conflicting buffer-local mappings if that's important to you, rather than forcing that mapping globally this way (seems like it could lead to a hard-to-track down bug if you ever _do_ want to override a buffer to have a specific `gd` mapping.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Do you know how to disable conflicting mapping? I have not been able to find a way. But I found that for `vim-go` plugin can set `let g:go_def_mapping_enabled=0` for disable remap.

Comment: Generally you need to look at the plugins documentation, yes

Answer (score 0):

the answer from Luc Hermitte `:SplitIfNotOpen4COC` didn't work on my case. but, combining between Mateus C answer with Luc Hermitte answer seems to be worked for me after i added :

```
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
nmap <silent> gy <Plug>(coc-type-definition)
nmap <silent> gi <Plug>(coc-implementation)
nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)
```

to jump to definition. i also added :

```
let g:coc_user_config = {}
let g:coc_user_config['coc.preferences.jumpCommand'] = [it is up to you]
```

i changed `it is up to you` with :

`split` to split between window horizontally

`tabe` to jump to reference on a new window

`vsplit` to split between window vertically

Answer (score 0):

Somehow none of the above answers worked for me. Below did the trick in my case:

```
nmap <silent> F <Plug>(coc-definition)
nnoremap <silent> F :call <SID>jump_definition()<CR>
function! s:jump_definition()
    call CocAction('jumpDefinition', 'vsplit')
endfunction
```

Comment: The second mapping overrides the first; are both needed? Why? Also, the second mapping is very similar to some mappings in other answers; curious that it didn't work for you.